# aws lambda didn't convert json request to POJO

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-sam-cli

I have a lambda function:

```
package org.smarter.note;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.LambdaLogger;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;

public class AddNoteRequestHandler implements RequestHandler<NewNoteRequest, Note> {

    private NoteRepository notes;
    private LambdaLogger logger;

    @Override
    public Note handleRequest(NewNoteRequest newNote, Context context) {
        init(context);

        log("creating note: " + newNote.toJson());

        notes.create(newNote);

        return new Note();
    }

    private void log(String message) {
        logger.log(String.format("%s\n", message));
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        this.logger = context.getLogger();
        this.notes = new NoteRepository();
    }
}
```

Then when I am testing the lambda using sam local, and send a request:

```
{
    "title": "hello",
    "content": "body"
}
```

I am expecting the json converted to `NewNoteRequest` automatically, but it didn't. here is the log:

```
You can now browse to the above endpoints to invoke your functions.
You do not need to restart/reload SAM CLI while working on your functions,
changes will be reflected instantly/automatically. You only need to restart
SAM CLI if you update your AWS SAM template.

2017/12/28 11:06:57 Invoking org.smarter.note.AddNoteRequestHandler (java8)
2017/12/28 11:06:57 Decompressing /Work/smarter-serverless/build/distributions/smarter-serverless.zip
2017/12/28 11:06:57 Mounting /private/var/folders/gv/m43y5g9x1xdc9f2kc2p0kpz00000gp/T/aws-sam-local-1514430417742696978 as /var/task:ro inside runtime container
START RequestId: bf0f77d3-198d-4211-ab9e-4c85a7c5de22 Version: $LATEST
creating note: {title=null, content=null}
```

my sam local template:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion : '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Resources:
  notes:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: org.smarter.note.AddNoteRequestHandler
      CodeUri: ./build/distributions/smarter-serverless.zip
      Runtime: java8
      Events:
        PostEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /notes
            Method: post
```

The POJO:

```
package org.smarter.note;

import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.Item;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

class NewNoteRequest implements DynamoDBItem, Json {
    private String title;
    private String content;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    @Override
    public Item item() {
        return new Item()
                .withString("title", this.title)
                .withString("content", this.content);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> toJson() {
        HashMap<String, Object> json = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        json.put("title", this.title);
        json.put("content", this.content);
        return json;
    }
}
```

Also the dependencies are:

```
dependencies {
    compile(
            "com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-core:1.1.0",
            "com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-events:1.1.0"
    )
}
```

I cannot figure out which part is wrong, AWS document says it can do the mapping directly. Please help.

Comment: Having this same problem. Frustrating. Did you ever solve it Jakim? There doesn't seem to be anyway to debug it. I see the JSON payload sent from the API Gateway is correct, and the same payload works correctly when I test the Lambda function by itself. The POJO gets instantiated by Lambda, but it never calls the set*() methods to set the fields passed in the JSON payload.

Comment: @Mark Sorry I got no luck on this, I have totally quit on aws lambda.

Comment: Thanks, @Jakim for responding. Sorry to hear you have quit on Lambda, but I understand. It's not very intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

I did solve my version of this problem. Under "Integration Request" I had "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" checked. Unchecking it caused the POJO to get populated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  To resolve it, I had to unselect the Lambda Proxy integration option in the corresponding API Gateway configuration and then deploy it to a stage.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the mounts to my sam local template and point that mounts to this file {
"title": "hello",
"content": "body"
}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).